# How to authorize request to a Google Calendar using OAuth access token?

Tags: .net, oauth, google-calendar-api

I read about OAuth so I understand the basic principles. What I can't seem to get is how to authorize a request to a Google Calendar API (I'm using v3) if I have an access token and a calendar id. 
The application that I work on is supposed to write data both to our db and to the Google Calendar. So when a user authorizes my app to access his calendar, I get back an access token and a calendar id. My question is what do I do next? 
I read about a dozen articles on the subject, only one of them have [a complete example](https://github.com/nanovazquez/google-calendar-sample) that uses ASP.NET MVC 4 - but the problem is it uses outdated NuGet packages which Google unlisted. Tried to port it, but class names, method names and parameter lists all changes so now I do not know what to do.

 P.S. Of course I saw Google docs on using OAuth in ASP.NET MVC, but that does not help me much because I can't figure out where to put the access token.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a Bearer token, you're code should look something like:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
result = webClient.UploadString(Url, "POST", PostData);
```

The raw request would look something like (ignoring the POST/GET difference):

```
GET /calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList/{calendarId} HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer <bearer-token>
```

I suggest testing this using the [Google OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) to get familiar with the API.

Comment: that's using plain .NET, I was expecting something using Google API or DotNetAuth library

Comment: [Google example in VB](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Calendar.VB.ConsoleApp/Program.vb?repo=samples).  I personally find the Google code extremely bloated and overly complicated for such a simple API.

Comment: the example shows a way of accessing a Google Account without an access token. argh, I feel really stupid right now

Comment: In general the DotNetAuth library (as far as I am aware) is used for authenicating with OAuth, and not something you can just plug into another .Net Framework and use right away.  That is pretty much why I rolled my own OAuth2 authentication and Google API frameworks, I spent less time making it work, then trying to figure out how to get the frameworks to work at all.